# What data-calc-type means?

Tags: html, button

I have a question about type of button. What data-calc-type means in this code?

```
<label for="x">x: </label><input id="x" type="number" placeholder="0"/>
<label for="y">y: </label><input id="y" type="number" placeholder="0"/>
<label for="z">z: </label><input id="z" type="number" placeholder="0"/>

<div id="calculations">
  <button data-calc-type="area">Pole</button>
  <button data-calc-type="circuit">Obwód</button>
  <button data-calc-type="volume">Objetość</button>
</div>

<p>Wynik: <span id="result"></span></p>
```

Comment: [Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Comment: the data attribute can be used to store a value and refer to it when scripting.

So basically you could have one event triggered by clicking any button and your script will know how to handle it by reading the attribute data-whatever

Comment: @MadeInDreams, i think you can post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The data-* attribute is very neat. It let you store data in it so you can refer to it with your script.

Exemple: You have many buttons in your page. All buttons do different action. Instead of calling many function you could call one function that deal with data attribue and process data accordingly.

```
if ($('#button_ID').attr('data-*') == "this attribute"){ //do something}
```